# Running a GUI application twice in java

Tags: java, spring, swing

I have a small gui swing application(Chat) in java, I need to run it multiple times, each time it should give me a GUI chat window,

It works fine for the first time, when I try to run the same application again in IntelliJ it wont generate anymore GUI window

any help is greatly appreciated thank you in advance

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException, SQLException {
    ClassPathXmlApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("sconfig.xml");
    CClient client = (CClient) context.getBean("simpleClient");
    client.init();
}
```

Application Context:

```
 <bean id="jmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory">
    <property name="brokerURL">
        <!-- value>tcp://localhost:61616</value -->
        <value>vm://localhost</value>
    </property>
</bean>

<!-- <bean id="pooledJmsConnectionFactory" class="org.apache.activemq.pool.PooledConnectionFactory"
      destroy-method="stop">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>-->
<bean id="destination" class="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQQueue">
    <constructor-arg value="jmsExample" />
</bean>

<bean id="jmsTemplate" class="org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="simpleClient" class="com.CClient">
    <property name="template" ref="jmsTemplate"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination" />
</bean>

<bean id="messageListener" class="com.ExampleListener" />

<!-- and this is the message listener container -->
<bean id="jmsContainer" class="org.springframework.jms.listener.DefaultMessageListenerContainer">
    <property name="connectionFactory" ref="jmsConnectionFactory"/>
    <property name="destination" ref="destination"/>
    <property name="messageListener" ref="messageListener" />
</bean>
```

Comment: You'll have to post your application context too.

Comment: Did you tried running it from the operative system (console or executing the jar)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no reason launching an application once works fine, and launching it a second time doesn't do anything, since they're launched in a different JVM. There could be a problem if the first launch tries to open a TCP socket, or lock a file, and the second launch tries doing the same thing.

But I think the explanation is that you checked the "single instance only" checkbox in the *Run Configuration*, which is precisely used to make IntelliJ only launch one instance of your application instance at once.

If that's not the case provide more details: what happens when you launch the second app? Do you get an exception? If so, what's the stack trace? If not, what does your application do?

Comment: yes both the applications are opening a same tcp scoket
        <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
could you plz tell me a good way to solve the problem,

Comment: Pass the port to open as argument, and use a different port for both instances. You're developing a server and have two servers try to listen on the same port. Suppose a client connects to your host on this port, which application would receive the message if they could both listen on the same socket?